# AppleScript to Show Album in Library?

Tags: itunes, music

I'm trying to create a macro to manipulate some music (iTunes) tracks. One thing that I see is available without a menu/keyboard shortcut is the `Show Album in Library` command.

[image]

Does anyone know how to emulate this function (available only via mouse click) with AppleScript?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380032/313842 See 4th and 5th blocks of code in this answer. Although it would mean fixed click coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

*Hmm - not sure if this answers the spirit of the question. I'll leave it for now, trash it if it becomes clear it isn't relevant.*

You can do it using the regular 'Application/Menu Title' shortcut structure - it doesn't have to be in a top menu for the system to be able to find it correctly.

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.
Click the + button.
Select iTunes in the drop-menu
Type the exact menu name - "Show Album in Library"
Add a hot-key.
Click Add.

[image]

<sup>It's already showing in the window because I'd already added it to test, before deciding to do the snapshot</sup>

Comment: This is new, to have right-click menu items in shortcut's menu title ! I uselessly installed cliclick that day: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380032/313842

Comment: With Music (1.2.5.7, Monterey), a 'Show Album in Library' shortcut won't work to navigate to the album of the currently playing song, as that appears in a context menu only. If you highlight a song in the Songs list, it will bring you to that album, as that is a main menu item.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to `tell application "Music" to reveal current track`. The problem with that is that it only works if the track was played from the library, rather than from a playlist. So, instead:

```
tell application "Music"
    set musiclist to first playlist whose special kind is Music
    set track_id to persistent ID of current track
    activate
    reveal (first track of musiclist whose persistent ID is track_id)
end tell
```

The `first playlist whose special kind is Music` is the built-in playlist that contains all the music in the library. We use `whose` to search that list for the current track's persistent ID and reveal that track.